# ffserver config for HLS

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, ffserver

I've installed `ffmpeg` version  `3.4-1` on `Ubuntu 16.04`, I set the configuration of `ffserver` for `HLS` to:

```
#/etc/ffserver.conf:

HTTPPort 8090
HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 2000
MaxClients 1000
MaxBandwidth 1000
CustomLog -

<Feed feed1.ffm>
File /tmp/feed1.ffm
FileMaxSize 50M
</Feed>

<Stream playlist.m3u8>
NoDefaults
VideoSize 720*576
Feed feed1.ffm
Format HLS
AudioBitRate 32
AudioChannels 1
AudioSampleRate 44100
VideoBitRate 64
VideoBufferSize 40
VideoFrameRate 25
AudioCodec mp2
VideoQMin 3
VideoQMax 31
Preroll 15
VideoCodec libx264
AVOptionVideo flags +global_header
</Stream>

<Stream stat.html>
Format status
ACL allow localhost
ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
</Stream>

<Redirect index.html>
URL http://www.ffmpeg.org/
</Redirect>
```

I ran ffserver on server with this config, then the other machine I ran below ffmpeg config:

```
ffmpeg  -i /dev/video0 -f alsa -ar 44100 -i hw:0  http://live.example.com:8090/feed1.ffm
```

On the ffserver side I encounter this errors:

```
Tue Nov 14 14:13:31 2017 [hls @ 0x55ed31333460]Opening '0.ts' for writing
Tue Nov 14 14:13:39 2017 [hls @ 0x55ed31333460]Opening '1.ts' for writing
Tue Nov 14 14:13:39 2017 [hls @ 0x55ed31333460]Opening '.tmp' for writing
Tue Nov 14 14:13:39 2017 [hls @ 0x55ed31333460]failed to rename file .tmp to 
Tue Nov 14 14:13:49 2017 [hls @ 0x55ed31333460]Opening '2.ts' for writing
Tue Nov 14 14:13:49 2017 [hls @ 0x55ed31333460]Opening '.tmp' for writing
Tue Nov 14 14:13:49 2017 [hls @ 0x55ed31333460]failed to rename file .tmp to 
Tue Nov 14 14:13:59 2017 [hls @ 0x55ed31333460]Opening '3.ts' for writing
Tue Nov 14 14:13:59 2017 [hls @ 0x55ed31333460]Opening '.tmp' for writing
Tue Nov 14 14:13:59 2017 [hls @ 0x55ed31333460]failed to rename file .tmp to 
Tue Nov 14 14:14:09 2017 [hls @ 0x55ed31333460]Opening '4.ts' for writing
Tue Nov 14 14:14:09 2017 [hls @ 0x55ed31333460]Opening '.tmp' for writing
Tue Nov 14 14:14:09 2017 [hls @ 0x55ed31333460]failed to rename file .tmp to
```

And the player doesn't show anything.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you fond a solution for this?

Comment: I use ffmpeg directly without ffserver. ffserver is deprecated

Comment: Hi Arash, what is the command you used using only ffmpeg in place of ffserver + ffmpeg ? Please suggest.